# CXJS using parameters in Controller

Tags: reactjs, cxjs

How can I use parameters in a controller of the functional component?

like https://docs.cxjs.io/concepts/functional-components

I make lets say a to do list app, with a list component with data binding and a todo entry component but the entry has so much logic that it has its own controller.

how can i access  these parameters in a controller like an enhanced example of the docs:

```
const LineChart = ({ data, chartStyle, lineStyle }) => <cx>
    <Svg style={chartStyle} controller={MyController}>
        <Chart offset="20 -20 -40 40" axes={{ x: { type: NumericAxis }, y: { type: NumericAxis, vertical: true } }}>
            <Gridlines/>
            <LineGraph data={data} lineStyle={lineStyle} />
        </Chart>
    </Svg>
</cx>;




    class MyController extends Controller {
        onInit() {
            //use Parameter chartStyle in code.
    var myparameter = {{chartStyle}}; //??? < how do i get the value 
    ....
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to the controller:

```
const LineChart = ({ data, chartStyle, lineStyle }) => <cx>
    <Svg style={chartStyle} controller={{ type: MyController, chartStyle }}>
        <Chart offset="20 -20 -40 40" axes={{ x: { type: NumericAxis }, y: { type: NumericAxis, vertical: true } }}>
            <Gridlines/>
            <LineGraph data={data} lineStyle={lineStyle} />
        </Chart>
    </Svg>
</cx>;
```

Comment: This is really useful!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to pass parameters to controllers, which I find more declarative, is to use a controller factory function and make the parameter available via function closure. Another benefit of this approach is that we can use a custom parameter name within the controller.

```
const LineChart = ({ data, chartStyle, lineStyle }) => <cx>
    <Svg style={chartStyle} controller={getController(chartStyle)}>
        <Chart offset="20 -20 -40 40" axes={{ x: { type: NumericAxis }, y: { type: NumericAxis, vertical: true } }}>
            <Gridlines/>
            <LineGraph data={data} lineStyle={lineStyle} />
        </Chart>
    </Svg>
</cx>;

// controller factory
function getController(style) { 
    return class MyController extends Controller {
        onInit() {
            // now `chartStyle` is available as `style` within controller via function closure
            console.log(style);
            ....
        }
    };
}
```